# Getting Python3 CgiBin to work not just Pyton2 with CgiBin on Osx

Tags: python, macos, apache, python-3.x, cgi-bin

I am not able to get Apache to work correctly on Mac.

Mac like Ubuntu carries multiple lines of Python.  Both Python 2.6 and 3.6 are installed on my computer.

I can get Python 2.6 to do a hello world.  But I want to use Python 3.6 and can not get that to work.

Can someone help me with what I need to change?

Here is an example of my web page that works for Python2.6/CgiBin/Apache/Osx

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- icoding: UTF-8 -*-

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print ""
print "Hello World!"
```

Here is the modified version that I did for Python3.6/CgiBin/Apache/Osx:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- icoding: UTF-8 -*-

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")
print ("")
print ("Hello World!")
```

## Note only one change, from python to python3

Comment: python3 -V returns Python 3.6
and 
python -V returns Python 2.6

Comment: Have you type 'which python' and 'which python3' ?

Comment: which python = /usr/local/bin/python and which python3 =/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: I got it to work with the revised code.

Comment: #!/usr/local/bin/python3 

import sys 
import os, cgi, sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n") 
print ()                              
print ("<html>") 
print ("<title>Some Title Here </title>") 
print ("<body>") 
print ("Hello World")
print ("</body>")                             
print ("</html>")

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3 

import sys 
import os, cgi, sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n") 
print ()                              
print ("<html>") 
print ("<title>Some Title Here </title>") 
print ("<body>") 
print ("Hello World")
print ("</body>")                               
print ("</html>")
```

It turns out it did not like the second line:

## -*- icoding: UTF-8 -*-